# What is the best method for accessing a resource which is non-deterministic?

Tags: http, rest

Lets say I am building a web service that is returning a random number?

Real world example: http://www.random.org/integers/?num=10&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new

random.org does this via GET method, which is not RESTful I think. Specs are saying that GET method should be idempotent.

What method would you suggest and what would your URL be?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985889/rest-get-a-random-number-get-or-post. GET is most likely the best candidate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem here. Being idempotent has nothing to do with returning the same thing all the time.